# How to get html5 video width on resize event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple video player:

```
<video id="v" controls width="640px" src="VIDEOHERE">
    <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
```

And this script:

```
    <script>
       var v = document.getElementById("v");
       v.addEventListener( "resize", function (e) {
           var width = this.videoWidth,
               height = this.videoHeight;
               alert(width);
       }, false );
    </script>
```

I would like to get the actual width and height of the video when the user clicked on the resize button and its resized.

Actually I'm trying to manage an overlay advertisement on this player. 
I have already made the overlay, but when I resize the video I need to resize the overlay too, but now I only get the actual width when my page load.

Comment: do you mean a resize of the window? in that case listening to the resize event in the window would be the way to go?

Comment: I means resize the player. Not the browser. There is a button on the player, when i click on it it resize the video to fullscreen. I would like to get that size and when it done.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a event to trigger when the user makes the video play in full screen. There's a number of events for the video here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp - but unfortunately "switch to full screen" is not one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's a `fullscreen` event on the video player.  You can try the default browser full screen, with the following code:

```
$(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange', function() {
    console.log('Do something when user goes into full screen mode');
});
```

More details on this on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode